# In what ways is Obamacare better/worse than the previous healthcare system in the US, now that we have real world information about how it operates?

Tags: affordable-care-act

Supporters of the Democratic party are generally very supportive of the ACA (aka Obamacare). On the other hand many Republicans are opposed to it and want to repeal it as soon as possible.

In what ways is the ACA better/worse than the previous laws in the US? I've seen some analysis back when the new health insurance law was passed, but it would be interesting to see how it played out in practice.

Better = helps more people get coverage or helps them get it cheaper. Worse = makes health coverage worse, increases prices, increases the budget deficit, etc.

Comment: You'll need to add some sort of qualifiers for better/worse or this will be all opinion-based. Is better covering more people? Lowering government spending on healthcare?

Comment: @Gramatik done.

Comment: Implicit in this question is the assumption that the ACA completely changed the healthcare system, rather than simply tweaking it a bit. I don't think that's the case at all.

Answer (score 2):

> *Better = helps more people get coverage or helps them get it cheaper.*

[The NYT reports](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/22/health/obamacare-health-insurance-numbers-nchs.html) that of 2017...

> 11.6 million had purchased their plans through the federal Health Insurance Marketplace or state-based exchanges established by the Affordable Care Act

In that more people were able to get insurance than before, and more people with pre-existing conditions were able to get insurance, and, overall, more people were insured, I'd say coverage was better.

> *Worse = makes health coverage worse, increases prices, increases the budget deficit, etc.*

In general, health care prices absolutely increased--but hard to say if it was due to the ACA, or just a continuation of existing trends. This chart from [Avalon Health Economics](http://www.avalonecon.com/) shows the ongoing trend pre-ACA and their forecast post-ACA. Note that this has been a rather steady trend for a long while:

[image]

Another chart from the Commonwealth Fund showing similar trending:

[image]

(Note: I haven't been able to find a more recent chart through 2017 that uses actual post-ACA data. Not sure why. Perhaps it is due to that data not being fully analyzed yet.)

As such, it's hard to say what the ACA contributed directly to in this regard. I think it's fair to say the ACA didn't *stop* this trend. However, if you ask Forbes if it contributed to it, you will find answers that say both [yes, it has](https://www.forbes.com/sites/theapothecary/2017/03/22/yes-it-was-the-affordable-care-act-that-increased-premiums/#1d1f5a4f11d2), and [no, it hasn't](https://www.forbes.com/sites/robbmandelbaum/2017/02/24/no-obamacare-hasnt-jacked-up-your-companys-insurance-rates/#10ef56543a01).

Final Note: The ACA isn't really a 'new' health care system. It's merely a way to extend the existing system (private insurers and medicare) to more people, along with a few new restrictions on what private insurers are allowed to do. Most of the problems with the 'previous' health care system are the same, as the system hasn't changed a whole lot.

Comment: Is the chart adjusted for inflation, or the decline in buying power of the US dollar?

Comment: @DrunkCynic I can't find details on that but on closer inspection, that's not a good chart. It looks like it was done in 2013 so those were projections rather than observations. Let me try and find a better graph.

Comment: @DrunkCynic wow...it's really hard to find an updated chart with this info that clearly states recent numbers alongside answering your question about inflation adjustment.

Comment: While an inflation adjusted chart would be stronger, an admission that such a chart couldn't be found would be sufficient. Was looking mostly for a disclaimer, since the chart didn't have one. While the percentage of GDP chart shows a trend that could account for inflation elsewhere, there are too many external factors. Try looking for spending per capita information instead.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_care_prices_in_the_United_States#/media/File:US_healthcare_cost_panel_v1.png) has nice graphs for %GDP, per capita, as well as % increase, though they also only go to 2014/2015.

Comment: Yes, that's a lot better. There's still an implication by putting all that under "(Is Obamamcare) worse", but at least it now clarifies pretty well in the very first sentence.

Comment: Oh. Also, I'd highly suggest deleting your comment to the question, and tacking it to the front of this answer. It makes a good executive summary.

Comment: Very difficult to tease out cause & effect, particularly with the GOP intentionally hamstringing and undermining the ACA. Refusing the Medicaid expansion generally led to less people covered, but a greater expense, so that hurts statistics. There was a fund to level market fluctuations and volatility, Rubio amended that out of existence, then everyone blamed the ACA when premiums spiked in some markets once that was removed, to cite just a couple examples. Enrollment period cut this year, advertising/outreach slashed to the bone. Failure of ACA? Failure caused by those trying to destroy it?